# MYSQL not working with Where

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I am trying to get data from a table to show in table manner.

```
$myid = 'First_User';
$checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='" . $myid . "';";
echo $checkQuery; // it returns SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='First_User';. I run in mySQL console , and it returns the record.
$result = mysql_query($checkQuery);     
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The above seems not able to fetch anything. But says `"Resource #3"`. No data seen.

```
$myid = 'First_User';
$checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase";

$result = mysql_query($checkQuery);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This works returning all data from MyDatabase. I do have First_User in MyDatabase.

Comment: Please don't learn database access using the old, deprecated MySQL extension; learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: is the id 'First_User' or is it in another column?

Comment: What are you displaying to get `Resource #3`, sounds like you're displaying `$result`; you need to display the `$row` array

Comment: Could you please post the output of print_r($row)?

Comment: yeap. id column has First_User. Wondering what is Resource#3.

Comment: Maybe because `id`'s structure is `int` and you try to look for `First_User` string from it. And if there is really `First_User` value, is it really in the `id` column?

Comment: print_r returns Array ( [0] => First_User [id] => First_User [1] => This is Address. [address] => This is Address. )

Comment: OP has to remove the `javascript` tag.

Comment: Using print_r($row), you will get your data

Comment: @Kay please show the code where you're actually displaying the results, everything else seems fine, especially if your print_r returns that..

Comment: this it what I am trying to do.

Comment: echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ID\" value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'/></td>";

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo $row[0];
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ID\" value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'/></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }

Comment: sorry. very new to posting.  :) when i echo $row[0] , nothing comes up. btw, how to go next line in this post. Pressing enter auto do "Add Commen."

Comment: please add this code in your question in proper formating

Answer (score 0):

Hi MySQL is table Orientated.

```
Select <table felds> , < table felds> From <table> Where ....
```

Comment: It looks like their table is called "MyDatabase" - the SELECT * works when omitting the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are trying to query, basically you have to do:

`SELECT * FROM your table_name WHERE field_name='Field_value';`

The database is usually defined on the driver you use to connect to the database in this case the deprecated

[mysql-connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
But as already mentioned you should use PDO is newer and safer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this ..

```
$checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='$myid'";
```

Comment: i try $checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='$myid'";. same no data fetched

Comment: Use a text box at your front end webpage and take the data from user and display it in the web page Like this:

Comment: if(isset($_REQUEST['Your button name'])){$text = $_REQUEST("Your Text box name");  $checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='$myid'"; $query=mysql_query($checkQuery);} and than echo the query ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$myid = 'First_User';
$checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='$myid'";
$result = mysql_query($checkQuery);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="ID" value='.$row[0].'></td>';
}
```

**Note :** Avoid using `mysql_*` functions. Use instead `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use mysql_connect, use MySQLi or PDO

I prefer PDO.

How to connect to PDO:

```
$db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Now you want to write your query and fetch

```
$query = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `MyDatabase` WHERE `id` = :id");
$query->execute(array(":id" => $myid));
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $user) {
    echo $user['id'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ID\" value=\"" echo $row['id'] "\" /></td>";
    echo "</tr>"
}
```

I hope I havne't missed anything off, but please read PDO documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php (or mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php )

And if you're using post data somewhere in your query, please see other posts on how to prevent mysql injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Answer (score 0):

Use It. And Additional Add `LIMIT` because your query will return only result. It's extra potential.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // or something else.  

$checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabase WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";

$results = mysqli_query($checkQuery);

if ($result) $user=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

// use now.

echo $user['user_name'];
echo $user['id'];
```